# Is it possible to change the Virtualbox Docker Machine's IP address?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, boot2docker, docker-swarm

By default on a VM, the Docker-Machine created will have the IP address of 192.168.99.100 
I want to know is there a way to change this IP. If Yes then how and if No then why?

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been [requested](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1709) but unfortunately is still not present. You can check the comments in the issue. There are some workarounds mentioned that might help you.

Comment: Your answer was helpful. Thanks.